Issue with PCB Document Update in Altium Designer
In Altium Designer, when I perform an "Update PCB Document," I receive the following message:
"Failed to Match 1 of 277 components using Unique Identifiers. Do you want to try and match the remaining components using their designators?"
I am not sure why this happened and what I should do next.When I compile the PCB Project, the compilation finishes successfully. But when I try to perform the Update, this error appears and I didn't find any other information. Is it possible to reset the Identifiers? Will that solve the problem? Can anyone provide some insight or advice on how to resolve this issue? I would be grateful if someone could help.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Most EDA tools handle SCH and PCB in separate processes.  Altium is no different in this respect -- well, it's in the same application, but different libraries support those functions.
Most tools track component changes/properties by designator.  But what happens if you want to check designators?  You better write down all of them by hand and change them on both (SCH/PCB) sides, good luck have fun.
Altium improves this process by attaching a Unique ID to each part.  These are synchronized when creating a part, or on the C, K (Project / Component Links) dialog in PCB view.  You can freely change properties of a component (footprint, designator, description, etc.) and keep them synchronized.
Synchronization however is broken when copy-pasting parts, moving between sheets, etc.  UID conflicts can also happen when adding sheets to the design (e.g. saving two copies of a schematic, modifying one, adding the other back in), as saving the file doesn't change UIDs (this usually results in a dialog that there are duplicates, and simply resetting them solves it).
Altium then falls back on matching by designator, but per the above, this can fail, and without matches, parts will be deleted and re-added, etc.
The simple solution is to check links regularly.
My nervous/paranoid habit of checks is: (in PCB) check component links; import changes; component links again; import again; repour polygons; and later in development, run design rule check.

Interesting. Thanks for the tip. I don't use any version control, so I simply copy the folder where the project is located, paste it, change the name, and add the date. I'm afraid that this might have contributed to the problem too. Does this have any relation?

Some of these will become relevant if you're copying files back and forth between versions, the main thing is to keep UIDs 'U', and synchronized with PCB. It kinda just happens in the course of editing, whether within or between files. You can be mindful of what actions break links if you want, but the solution is the same, just re-match and link. I don't mind, I just do changes, check links and update.
